# Anime of little round guy with asian rice hat in the desert, lots of gangs and Mad Max stuff

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

I am trying to identify an anime from my childhood of a wanderer in the desert with a rice hat on. He fought with and alongside lots of Mad Max type characters, and wrecker-women. There were also balloon decoys of the main character that he deployed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's [*Desert Punk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_Punk). The main character has a rice hat on, as you say, and he is also short. It makes sense that there were Mad Max characters, because the show is set after the apocalypse. I also believe that in the first episode he uses balloon decoys.

[image: Image of Desert Punk shown wearing a "rice hat"]

Comment: Thanks mate! Much appreciated. Have yourself a kick-ass weekend.

Comment: Thanks. Just make sure you hit the checkmark. Enjoy the show - you can find it on Hulu.

Comment: [The show on Hulu](https://www.hulu.com/series/desert-punk-98fa39de-5732-4d57-84b6-50e162dca27e)